# error on line 3 at column 13: error parsing attribute name

Tags: xml

Sorry for the question, I am a noob. I am trying to create an XML file. I downloaded a template to create one and I get this error

> Error on line 3 at column 13: error parsing attribute name

I do not know if I am supposed to type the code differently, I am just following instructions that I could find online. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
    <loc>http://www.mylabzoe.com/</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoe15.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeTongueHangingOut2.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeWithBigBone.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeLayingWithHope.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeLickingTheo.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeChristmas.jpg
    <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/What_Labs_Love_To_Do.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeJump.JPG
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/dogpark1.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoefetch0.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoerolling.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/GoofyPic.jpg
    </image:image>
    <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/The_History_And_Genetics_Of_Labs.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoe15.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/Zoe_Beach.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeTongueHangingOut.jpg
    <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/The%20Recommended%20Toys%20for%20Labs.html</loc>
<lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/How%20To%20Discipline%20Your%20Dog%20The%20Right%20Way.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/Zoewinter.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoesniffing.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoesquirrel.jpg
        <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeSittingHappy.jpg
<lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.6</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: xmlns:XXXX is a special kind of name used for declaring namespaces, and it can be used only as an attribute name, not as an element name.

Answer (score 1):

The XML shall be well-formed. I modified the root element to house all namespaces, and paired all starting tags with matching closing tags. To see it, just compare the XML below with yours.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.mylabzoe.com/</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoe15.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeTongueHangingOut2.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeWithBigBone.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeLayingWithHope.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeLickingTheo.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeChristmas.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/What_Labs_Love_To_Do.html</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeJump.JPG</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/dogpark1.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoefetch0.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoerolling.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/GoofyPic.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/The_History_And_Genetics_Of_Labs.html</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoe15.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/Zoe_Beach.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeTongueHangingOut.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/The%20Recommended%20Toys%20for%20Labs.html</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.7</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/B_HTML/How%20To%20Discipline%20Your%20Dog%20The%20Right%20Way.html</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/Zoewinter.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoesniffing.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/zoesquirrel.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:loc>https://www.mylabzoe.com/C_Images/ZoeSittingHappy.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2019-09-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```